# $geoNear (aggregate pipeline) not returning correct documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am not getting the correct results returned when using `$geoNear` in the aggregate pipeline.  The same query using a typical find() query (using `$near`) does in fact return the right results.

**BUT**, when removing the equality condition (on `schedule.key`), both queries return the correct data.

#### `$geoNear` using aggregate pipeline:

```
db.place.aggregate(
[
    { 
        $geoNear: { 
            spherical: true,
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 18.416145, -33.911973 ] },
            distanceField: "dist"
        }
    },
    { 
        $match: { 
            "schedule.key": { "$eq": "vo4lRN_Az0uwOkgBzOERyw" } 
        } 
    }
])
```

#### `$near` find query:

```
db.place.find(
    { 
        "point" : { 
            $near: { 
                type: "Point", 
                coordinates: [ 18.416145,-33.911973 ] 
            } 
        }, 
        "schedule.key" : { 
            $eq : "vo4lRN_Az0uwOkgBzOERyw" 
        }
    })
```

A document in this collection looks something like this:

```
{
    "_id" : UUID("da6ccbb1-3c7a-45d7-bc36-a5e6007cd919"),
    "schedule" : {
        "_id" : UUID("587de5b7-a744-4b28-baa8-e6efb5f7f921"),
        "key" : "vo4lRN_Az0uwOkgBzOERyw"
    },
    "point" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            18.425102, 
            -33.922153
        ]
    },
    "name" : "Cape Town"
}
```

I have created the appropriate index on the point field:

```
db.place.ensureIndex( { "point" : "2dsphere" } );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the "same" query at all. There is a distinct difference in using a separate [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage, since the "filtering" is only done "after" the "nearest resuts" are found. This means that you potentially return "less" results since the criteria is not issued in combination.

That's why there is a `"query"` option in [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/):

```js
db.place.aggregate(
[
    { 
        $geoNear: { 
            spherical: true,
            near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 18.416145, -33.911973 ] },
            distanceField: "dist",
            query: {
                "schedule.key": { "$eq": "vo4lRN_Az0uwOkgBzOERyw" } 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Now that's the same query. Or it would be exactly the same if you used [`$nearSphere`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/). Since [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) does not account for the curvature of the earth in distance calcuations. [`$nearSphere`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) and [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) does.

But the main point is combining with the `"query"` option, since that's the only way you truly get both criteria considered in the initial search.

Comment: I didn't realise that the geoNear stage actually has a limit on documents returned - thanks.

Comment: @davenewza It's not just the "limit" but that the "two" stages do not "coalesce" as a single query, like you originally seemed to think it did. It's actually a personal gripe of mine that in "some" cases the aggregation pipeline processing actually does "coalesce" stages together. Personally I think it should not, as just about every case breeds bad programming habits where you really should be aware of the single stage usage. But this is one certain case of "Apples and Oranges" in terms of the criteria given.