# combine $geoNear with $match, while ensuring number of docs returned (mongodb)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to fetch 20 documents that are `within certain distance` **AND** have `active: true` **AND** `have distances returned`. But the problem is:

1) If using mongodb query, combine`$nearSphere`, `active: true`, and`limit(20)`, it will correctly query documents **until reaches 20 documents**. But, **it does not return the distances**.

2) If using mongodb aggregation as follows, **it will return the distances, but** the `$match` stage could kill off some documents that do not have `active: true`. Thus, the number of docs returned cannot be ensured.

```
var operation = [
   { "$geoNear": { "distanceField": "distance", "limit": 20 }},
   { "$match": { status: 'accepted' } }
}];

model.aggregate(operation, function (err, docs){
    // each doc has `distance`, but 2nd operation could 
    // remove some document, thus the number of docs returned
    // cannot be ensured
});
```

How do I ensure a certain number of documents will get returned? (like the 1st method), AND having the mongodb-calculated distance as well (like the 2nd method)?

Comment: As explained in the [answer on the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36714587/geonear-aggregate-pipeline-not-returning-correct-documents/36714805#36714805) the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline stage has as `"query"` property that is used for this exact purpose.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, this is perfect!